# std::rel_ops functionality as a base class. Is that appropriate solution?

Tags: c++, templates, comparison-operators

I've implemented the functionality of std::rel_ops namespace as a template base class (it defines all comparison operators using only operators < and ==). For me it's a bit weird that it works (so far) properly, also I'm concerned about the 'hacks' used. Can anyone assess the following code and say if I'm just lucky it to work or it's standard practice to do things like that.

```
template <typename T>
class RelationalOps {
public:

    inline bool operator!=(const T &rhs) const
    {
        const T& lhs = static_cast<const T&>(*this);
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    inline bool operator<=(const T &rhs) const
    {
        const T& lhs = static_cast<const T&>(*this);
        return ((lhs < rhs) || (lhs == rhs));
    }

    inline bool operator>(const T &rhs) const
    {
        const T& lhs = static_cast<const T&>(*this);
        return !((lhs < rhs) || (lhs == rhs));
    }

    inline bool operator>=(const T &rhs) const
    {
        const T& lhs = static_cast<const T&>(*this);
        return !(lhs < rhs);
    }
};
```

Comment: You are using a C++ idiom called the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP). It's a powerful method that I have used many times myself. A reference to the T is sometimes done with a special method: `T& Base() const { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }`. If you're learning you're doing fine. If you want to define operators you should look at Boost.Operators, just like usta recommended.

Comment: I probably should also suggest better ways of defining operators like this if you ever need to do it by hand: define `lhs<=rhs` in terms of `!(rhs<lhs)` and `lhs>rhs` in terms of `rhs<lhs`.

Comment: The `inline' specification on all those functions is redundant, as functions defined in a class body are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why not use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)?